# How to interpret Cost vs Bytes in Oracle explain plan?

Tags: oracle, sql-execution-plan

I have a query where I am doing join between two tables and there are many filters.
I run the explain plan, I see

```
cost:214, Bytes: 6154, Cardinality:67
```

To reduce the cost, I created a function based index on one column which was being used earlier too as one of the filters in the query. I gathered table stats and then gathered index stats. Now, I ran the explain plan again. This time I see

```
cost:214, Bytes: 122604, Cardinality:1202
```

My question: What is the relation between Cost & Bytes? Why the number of Bytes and Cardinality increased? Shouldn't creating function based index should have reduced Cost a little?

Can someone please help me understand this?

Comment: To answer all questions, please post SQL query and EXPLAIN PLAN output.

Answer (score 2):

Cost is documented in the SQL Tuning Guide (but not the number of bytes):

> The optimizer cost model accounts for the machine resources that a
> query is predicted to use.
>
> The cost is an internal numeric measure that represents the estimated
> resource usage for a plan. The cost is specific to a query in an
> optimizer environment. To estimate cost, the optimizer considers
> factors such as the following:
>
> ```
> System resources, which includes estimated I/O, CPU, and memory
>
> Estimated number of rows returned (cardinality)
>
> Size of the initial data sets
>
> Distribution of the data
>
> Access structures
> ```
>
> Note:
>
> The cost is an internal measure that the optimizer uses to compare
> different plans for the same query. You cannot tune or change cost.
>
> The execution time is a function of the cost, but cost does not equate
> directly to time. For example, if the plan for query A has a lower
> cost than the plan for query B, then the following outcomes are
> possible:
>
> ```
> A executes faster than B.
>
> A executes slower than B.
>
> A executes in the same amount of time as B.
> ```
>
> Therefore, you cannot compare the costs of different queries with one
> another. Also, you cannot compare the costs of semantically equivalent
> queries that use different optimizer modes.

See [Query optimizer concepts in SQL tuning guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql/query-optimizer-concepts.html#GUID-06129ACE-36B2-4534-AE68-EDFCAEBB3B5D).

Don't forget that EXPLAIN PLAN is only the estimated plan.
To check what the actual plan is really doing use DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR or SQL trace.